# How to Customize the size of the Folder & Files in the desktop?

Tags: files, icons, directory, customization, .desktop

There are some folders in my desktop which seems large in size (Bulky) !!!

No Option to change it, Even Right-Click !!!

I would like to Customize it. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

From Settings -> Displays;

There is a place that named "Scale for menu and title bars" or "UI scale"

You can use there.

One more option unity-tweak-tool;

To install;

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To Run from terminal ;

```
unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: hmmm Thanks @al0s It doesn't work for me. No change in size of the Files and Folder.

Comment: :) @Sridhar, are you using 10.04? and what is your resolution?

Comment: Just try unity-tweak-tool. Maybe it works.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04, Resolution 1360*768. I am using Unity-Tweak Tool only. But still no options to customize. @al0s

Comment: Is it occurs suddenly or after a new instillation?

Comment: It's Default size only, but looks ugly when icons increases. @al0s

Comment: "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor n" give a number to n first 0 then 1 after up to you, just give a change to this command from terminal.